# The sum of subspace of finite dimension with a closed set is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

In [Banach-Hilbert Spaces, Vector Measures and Group Representations](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4998), 
P142 7-4.9 Corollary Let $M$ be a closed vector subspace of a normed
space $E$. Then for every finite dimensional vector subspace $N$ of $E$, the sum $M+N$ is a closed vector subspace of $E$.
This also can be found on [Sum of closed subspaces of normed linear space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639570/sum-of-closed-subspaces-of-normed-linear-space)

However, my exercise is not the sum of two subspace, but the sum of subspace of finite dimension with a closed set.

Let $M$ be a vector subspace of a normed space $E$, and $N$ be a finite
dimensional vector subspace of $E$. Assume that $M\cap N=\{0\}$, let $K$ be a closed subset in $M$, and $K\cap
N=\emptyset$. I would like to know whether $N+K$ is closed.

I feel that it is closed. Is the following proof right?

Let $\left\{  g_{n}\right\}  $ be the bases of $N$, and $\left\{
e_{m}\right\}  $ be the bases of $M$. For any $a_{i}g_{n}\in N$ and $b_{i}%
e_{m}\in K$, then $c_{i}=a_{i}g_{n}+b_{i}e_{m}\in N+K$. If $c_{i}=a_{i}%
g_{n}+b_{i}e_{m}\rightarrow c=ag_{n}+be_{m}+dh_{o}\in E$, where $h_{o}$ are
the remains bases of $E$. We must have $d=0$, $a_{i}\rightarrow a$ and
$b_{i}\rightarrow b$. and thus $c\in N+K$.

Comment: Consider $\pi : E\to E/N$, the natural quotient map. Since $N$ is a closed subspace, $\pi$ is a continuous and open map. From this, you can conclude that $K+N = \pi^{-1}(\pi(K))$ is a closed set.

Comment: But the image of a closed set  under a quotient map need not be closed. E.g., for the first projection $\pi:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and  $K=\lbrace (x,y): x>0, y\ge 1/x\rbrace$.

Comment: @Jochen: You are right, and this also answers the OP!

Comment: the examples in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed are from the same bases. But here the two sets come from different set of basis. I still think the sum is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

- $E=\ell^2$,
- $M$ is the space of sequences $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ with finitely many nonzero elements, and such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k=0$
- $N$ is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by the first standard basis vector $e_1$.
- $K=\{v_n\}$ where $v_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}(e_k-e_1)$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$. This is a closed subset of $M$, since the sequence $v_n$ has no convergent subsequence.

On the other hand, the sum $N+K$ contains the sequence $w_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}e_k$. This sequence has a limit in $\ell^2$, and this limit, having infinitely many nonzero entries, is not in $M+N$, hence is not in $K+N$.

---

Note that the space $M$ is not closed in the above example, but you did not require it to be closed in your formulation.

It it was closed, then the sum $M+N$ would be isomorphic to direct sum $M\circ N$, and therefore $K+N$ would be homeomorphic to the product of two closed sets, hence closed.