# Product of closed sub-groups in topological groups

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

We know that if $G$ is a topological group and $C \subseteq G$ is compact and $A \subseteq G$ is closed, then $AC$ , $CA$ are closed.

Is it right to say:

> The product of two closed subgroups in topological groups is  closed?

Answer (score 2):

This is false: [sum of two closed subspaces of a Banach space need not be closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786792/17929).

Comment: do you have an example in topological group? i didn't get it. thanks.

Comment: @adin, closed subspaces of a Banach space are subgroups of the topological group that is the Banach space