# Distance between closed affine sets

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

In the Banach space $X$, we define the distance between two sets $A$ and $B$ as $$d(A,B)=\inf \{||a-b||: a\in A,b\in B\}.$$ Let $M$ and $N$ be closed subspaces of $X$. Given $x, y \in X$, assume that $x+M$ and $y+N$ are disjoint. Can we concude that $d(x+M,y+N)>0$?

Comment: I don't remember much of functional analysis, but if you define $T(u,v)=u-v$ on $X\times X$ I think you can apply the closed graph theorem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a category of counter examples :

In any infinite dimensional normed vector space $X$, There are two closed subspace, $M$ and $N$ such that $M+N$ is **not**  closed . Then the closed subspace $Y : = \overline{M+N}$ of $X$ contains an element, say $y \in Y$ which is not in $M+N$. Then it is easy to verify that $(y+M )\cap N = \emptyset .$

Observe that $$0=d(y,M+N) = d(y+M ,N)$$

P.S: 
As an example of  such $M$ and $N$ in Hilbert space see:     [Sum of closed spaces is not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1786739/219176)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So what about the conclusion if we assume that $M$ and $N$ are closed convex cones, instead of closed subspaces?

Comment: @Math253  any subspace is cone too

Comment: Thanks. Sorry that my question is not clear. Acttually what I mean is that $M$ and $N$  are only closed convex cones but not closed closed subspaces. In this case the equality $d(y,M+N)=d(y+M,N)$ may not true.

Comment: So your question is that , you have two closed convex cones which are not subspace , then you translate them so that they don't intersect each other!

and you want see if they  have positive distance.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my new question. Thanks

Comment: @Math253  I am very positive  still the answer is NO ! but I don't  know any counter example on top of my mind right now ! you better ask it in separate question !

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it