# Sum of subspaces is dense but not all of the Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Find two closed linear subspaces $N,M$ of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ such that $N+M$ is dense but $N+M\neq H$.

I have been working on this problem from the exercises from John Conway's Functional Analysis and can't seem to make progress.

Comment: You can fins an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786739/sum-of-closed-spaces-is-not-closed