# Direct sum decomposition of Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, projection, direct-sum

I want to prove the following theorem.

**Theorem** Let $X_1$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $X$ and $M$ be a closed with $X$ such that $M\cap X_1$={0}. Then $X_2=X_1\oplus M$ is a closed subspace of $X$. Moreover, the operator $P$ defined by
\begin{align*}
Px=\left\{
   \begin{array}{cc}
   x&(x\in M)\\
   0&(x\in X_1)
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
then, $P\in B(X)$. ($B(X)$ is the set of bounded linear functionals from $X$ to $X$ whose domain of definition is the whole $X$.)

**My view**

Suppose it was shown that $P$ is a bounded operator on $X_2$.
Then we show that $X_2$ is closed. Assuming $x_n\in X_2$ and $x_n\to x$ in $X$, from the boundedness of $P$, $\{Px_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence of $M$. Since $M$ is a closed subset of Banach space, it is complete, so $\{Px_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to some $m\in M$. Therefore, $\{(I-P)x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x-m$. Call this $z$: $z=x-m\in X_1$. Thus, $x_n=Px_n+(I-P)x_n\to m+z\in X_2$, and since $x=m+z$, $x\in X_2$, and $X_2$ is closed.

The problem here is the boundedness of $P$. From the definition of the operator norm, I want to compute $\|P\|$, but I can't show that it is finite.
\begin{align*}
\|P\|&=\sup_{x\in M_2,x\neq 0}\frac{\|Px\|}{\|x\|}=\sup_{m+x_1\neq 0,m\in M,x_1\in X_1}\frac{\|m\|}{\|m+x_1\|}=\sup_{\|m\|=1,m\in M,x_1\in X_1}\frac{1}{\|m+x_1\|}
\end{align*}
I think we can transform this far, but we need to show that no matter how we take $m\in M,x_1\in X_1$, this denominator will not be $0$.

Comment: This is not true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786739/sum-of-closed-spaces-is-not-closed

Comment: In above link $M \cap N=\{0\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hmm... In general, we know that this holds if $X$ is a normed space and $M$ is finite dimensional, but I have seen statements that say it can be proved if $X$ is a Banach space and $M$ is closed in $X$. Is this still a misprint? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where did you find this statement? It is definitely false.