Is closed the sum of closed subspaces in a Banach space over $\mathbb{R}$?
Let be $X$ a Banach space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let be $Y$ and $Z$ two closed subspaces of $X$.
Is true that $Y + Z$ is a closed subspace of $X$?
My intuition says no, but I couldn't find a counterexample.
Thanks for your help.

Are you looking for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786739/?
