# Is the closure of the span equal to the span of union closed spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a infinite dimensional Banach space over the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$ be a sequence of linear independent vectors in $V$

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ be a fixed positive integer

I would like to know if it is true that:

$$
\overline
{
\operatorname{span}
(\{v_n\}_{n \geq 1})
}
=
\operatorname{span}
\left(
\{v_n\}_{n \leq m} 
\bigcup
\overline
{
\operatorname{span}
(\{v_n\}_{n \geq m+1})
}
\right)
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E_m = \operatorname{span}(\{v_n\}_{n \leq m})$ and $E'_m = \operatorname{span}(\{v_n\}_{n \geq m+1})$. We obviously have
$$\operatorname{span}(\{v_n\}_{n \geq 1}) = E_m + E'_m \subset E_m + \overline{E'_m}  = \operatorname{span}(E_m \cup \overline{E'_m}) \\
= \operatorname{span}(\{v_n\}_{n \leq m}) \cup  \overline{E'_m}) \subset \overline{\operatorname{span}(\{v_n\}_{n \geq 1})} .$$
It therefore suffices to show that $E_m + \overline{E'_m}$ is closed. But this is well-known because $E_m$ is finite-dimensional and $\overline{E'_m}$ is closed. See [Sum of closed subspaces of normed linear space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/639570).

Comment: thansk for your answer